# Обновление графиков matplotlib по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, matplotlib, qt-designer

Не совсем понимаю, как связать отдельный виджет в оконном приложении, созданным в *Qt Designer* с помощью *PyQt5*, с кнопкой.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отрисовывались графики (уже на созданных осях в отдельном виджете), используя вводимые значения в полях в этом же приложении. При последующем нажатии на кнопку так же заново отрисовывались графики.

Код, созданный *Qt Designer*:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(785, 594)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.inoutA1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 101, 31))
        self.inoutA1.setObjectName("inoutA1")
        self.inoutf1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 101, 31))
        self.inoutf1.setObjectName("inoutf1")
        self.inoutphi1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 101, 31))
        self.inoutphi1.setObjectName("inoutphi1")
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 90, 104, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.inoutphi2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 90, 104, 31))
        self.inoutphi2.setObjectName("inoutphi2")
        self.inoutf2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 104, 31))
        self.inoutf2.setObjectName("inoutf2")
        self.inoutA2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 104, 31))
        self.inoutA2.setObjectName("inoutA2")
        self.inoutphi3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 90, 101, 31))
        self.inoutphi3.setObjectName("inoutphi3")
        self.inoutf3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 50, 101, 31))
        self.inoutf3.setObjectName("inoutf3")
        self.inoutA3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 10, 101, 31))
        self.inoutA3.setObjectName("inoutA3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(285, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.inoutfd = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutfd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 101, 31))
        self.inoutfd.setObjectName("inoutfd")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 21, 20))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.inoutN = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 104, 31))
        self.inoutN.setObjectName("inoutN")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 16, 21))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.btnplot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnplot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 101, 31))
        self.btnplot.setObjectName("btnplot")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 169, 771, 371))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 785, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Виджет, в котором должны отрисовываться графики, указан выше под названием widget

Код с функцией, рисующая те самые графики:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_graph(A1, A2, A3, f1, f2, f3, phi1, phi2, phi3, fd, N):
    tstep = 1 / fd
    t = np.linspace(0, (N-1)*tstep, N)
    fstep = fd / N
    f = np.linspace(0, (N-1)*fstep, N)
    y = A1*np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*tstep*t+phi1) + A2*np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*tstep*t+phi2) +A3*np.sin(2*np.pi*f3*tstep*t+phi3)
    X = np.fft.fft(y) #X - будет серией комплексных чисел
    X_mag = np.abs(X) / N #Нормализация величины X

    f_plot = f[0:int(N/2+1)]
    X_mag_plot = 2 * X_mag[0:int(N/2+1)]
    X_mag_plot[0] = X_mag_plot[0] / 2

    #//////////////////////
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (4, 2))
    ax[0].set(xlabel='time, s', ylabel='y', title='Сигнал')
    ax[1].set(xlabel='freq, Hz', ylabel='y', title='Частотный спектр')

    ax[0].plot(t, y, '.-')
    ax[1].plot(f_plot, X_mag_plot, '.-')

    ax[0].grid()
    ax[1].grid()

    fig.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()

plot_graph()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваша реализация с построение графиков в отдельном окне.

Если вы хотите поместить свои графики в основное окно приложения, то посмотрите как это может выглядеть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a217323%20%20%5bpyqt5%5d%20matplotlib .

Потом, если вам надо, попробуйте выполнить свою реализацию.

Если что-то будет не получаться - зададите новый вопрос и пожалуйста, ваш пример должен быть  [минимально-воспроизводимым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(785, 594)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.inoutA1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 101, 31))
        self.inoutA1.setObjectName("inoutA1")
        self.inoutf1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 101, 31))
        self.inoutf1.setObjectName("inoutf1")
        self.inoutphi1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 101, 31))
        self.inoutphi1.setObjectName("inoutphi1")
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 90, 104, 31))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.inoutphi2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 90, 104, 31))
        self.inoutphi2.setObjectName("inoutphi2")
        self.inoutf2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 104, 31))
        self.inoutf2.setObjectName("inoutf2")
        self.inoutA2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 10, 104, 31))
        self.inoutA2.setObjectName("inoutA2")
        self.inoutphi3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutphi3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 90, 101, 31))
        self.inoutphi3.setObjectName("inoutphi3")
        self.inoutf3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutf3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 50, 101, 31))
        self.inoutf3.setObjectName("inoutf3")
        self.inoutA3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutA3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 10, 101, 31))
        self.inoutA3.setObjectName("inoutA3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('0', self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('2', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel('3', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 16, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel('4', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel('5', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel('6', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel('7', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel('8', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(285, 90, 21, 21))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel('9', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 50, 16, 21))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.inoutfd = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutfd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 101, 31))
        self.inoutfd.setObjectName("inoutfd")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel('10', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 21, 20))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.inoutN = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.inoutN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 104, 31))
        self.inoutN.setObjectName("inoutN")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel('11', self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 16, 21))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.btnplot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnplot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 101, 31))
        self.btnplot.setObjectName("btnplot")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 169, 771, 371))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 785, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

#        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
#        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.btnplot.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)
        
    def plot_graph(self):
        plt.close()
        
        A1 = int(self.inoutA1.toPlainText()) 
        A2 = int(self.inoutA2.toPlainText()) 
        A3 = int(self.inoutf3.toPlainText()) 
        f1 = int(self.inoutf1.toPlainText()) 
        f2 = int(self.inoutf2.toPlainText()) 
        f3 = int(self.inoutf3.toPlainText()) 
        phi1 = int(self.inoutphi1.toPlainText()) 
        phi2 = int(self.inoutphi2.toPlainText()) 
        phi3 = int(self.inoutphi3.toPlainText()) 
        fd = int(self.inoutfd.toPlainText()) 
        N = int(self.inoutN.toPlainText())           
        
        tstep = 1 / fd
        t = np.linspace(0, (N-1)*tstep, N)
        fstep = fd / N
        f = np.linspace(0, (N-1)*fstep, N)
        y = A1*np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*tstep*t+phi1) + A2*np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*tstep*t+phi2) +A3*np.sin(2*np.pi*f3*tstep*t+phi3)
        X = np.fft.fft(y)       # X - будет серией комплексных чисел
        X_mag = np.abs(X) / N   # Нормализация величины X

        f_plot = f[0:int(N/2+1)]
        X_mag_plot = 2 * X_mag[0:int(N/2+1)]
        X_mag_plot[0] = X_mag_plot[0] / 2

        #//////////////////////
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (4, 2))
        ax[0].set(xlabel='time, s', ylabel='y', title='Сигнал')
        ax[1].set(xlabel='freq, Hz', ylabel='y', title='Частотный спектр')

        ax[0].plot(t, y, '.-')
        ax[1].plot(f_plot, X_mag_plot, '.-')

        ax[0].grid()
        ax[1].grid()

        fig.savefig("test.png")
        plt.show()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle(".docx --> .pdf")
    ex.resize(540, 250)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное! Всё получилось)